# What does it mean for CUDA to have parallel kernels?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, operating-system, kernel

I'm reading an article about CUDA and it says "A CUDA program is a serial program with parallel kernels". My questions are:

1. What does it mean for it to be a serial program? I know that serial is the opposite of parallel, but what does that mean in terms of CUDA's code being run on different processors, different cores, etc? I know the point of CUDA is that it facilitates parallel programming, so I'm interested to know which part of it is serial.
2. What does it mean to have multiple kernels? I've always understood the kernel to be a part of the operating system, and I think CUDA is just software that runs within the operating system, right? How does CUDA have multiple kernels and how does it use them to achieve parallelism?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#programming-model

Answer (score 2):

1. A CUDA kernel is written from the standpoint of a single thread.  It answers the question "what will each thread do?"  A CUDA kernel gives a single definition for what every thread will do.  From the standpoint of a single thread, it appears to be a serial program.  However it becomes parallel at launch time, when many threads execute the same code, "in parallel".
2. I think you're misinterpreting.  CUDA has "parallel kernels" means that each kernel in CUDA has the opportunity to express (according to how it is written, and the specifics of CUDA concepts such as built-in variables)  and manifest (at launch time, across many threads of execution) parallelism.  It does not mean that CUDA inherently requires multiple kernels to express parallelism.  A single CUDA kernel launch is inherently parallel.

You may wish to read [the CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#programming-model).